# How to pipe binary data in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I tried to extract the Master Boot Record (MBR) via mmcat.exe in PowerShell and PowerShell ISE (Version 5.1.1). The outputted binary data is always bigger than 512 bytes. PowerShell 6.1.1 has still this problem.

```
$mmcat = "C:\Tools\sleuthkit\bin\mmcat.exe"
& $mmcat -t dos "$EWF_IMAGE" 0 > "$OUTPUT\Disk-Geometry\MBR.bin"
```

The issue is well decribed here:
[PowerShell’s Object Pipeline Corrupts Piped Binary Data](https://brianreiter.org/2010/01/29/powershells-object-pipeline-corrupts-piped-binary-data/)

Do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: `>` uses default UTF encoding. Did you try `& $mmcat -t dos "$EWF_IMAGE" 0 | "$OUTPUT\Disk-Geometry\MBR.bin" -encoding Ascii` ?

Comment: I tested it one minute ago...the output is 514 bytes. I tested also earlier -Encoding oem.

Comment: Try adding `-NoNewLine`

Comment: I played with -NoNewLine and -Encoding ascii & -Encoding oem...when the output has 512 bytes...for example the MBR Signature (55 AA) at the end is wrong.

Comment: When I run mmcat.exe with cmd.exe it is working...so this is maybe an approach for a workaround...run cmd.exe from inside the Windows PowerShell script.

Comment: Just checked my own MBR and it ends with 55 AA so I assume that's a *universal* marker?! I don't have mmcat but what is the output if you just show the result in the console?

Comment: You can download mmcat.exe here: https://github.com/sleuthkit/sleuthkit/releases/download/sleuthkit-4.6.4/sleuthkit-4.6.4-win32.zip

Comment: This [Get-ProcessOutputAsBinary](https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/01/18/redirecting-binary-output-in-powershell/) should work for you too but it's a shame it doesn't seem to work out of the box.

Comment: I found this script: http://powershellcookbook.com/recipe/WCiL/capture-and-redirect-binary-process-output , but I don't know how to deal with the arguments.

Comment: I would assume something like `Invoke-BinaryProcess mmcat -RedirectOutput -ArgumentList "-t dos '$EWF_IMAGE'"`

Comment: For posterity (because I constantly re-google the github issue) [here is the open ticket](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1908)

Answer (score 4):

**PowerShell 7** support **-AsByteStream** to pipe **binary data**:

```
Get-Content -AsByteStream .\original.bin | Set-Content -AsByteStream .\copied-file.bin
```

If you want to **concatenate** binary file use Add-Content:

```
Get-Content -AsByteStream .\original.bin | Add-Content -AsByteStream .\appended-file.bin
```

Comment: PS 5 has get-content -encoding byte

Comment: @js2010 The future PowerShell version will not support -Encoding Byte. It's replaced by -AsByteStream

Answer (score 2):

You can't pipe binary data in PowerShell. To work around, use `cmd.exe` like this:

```
$command = "C:\Tools\sleuthkit\bin\mmcat.exe -t dos `"$EWF_IMAGE`" 0 > `"$OUTPUT\Disk-Geometry\MBR.bin`""
cmd /c $command
```

You can read binary data like this:

```
[byte[]]$mbr = Get-Content -Path $OUTPUT\Disk-Geometry\MBR.bin -Encoding Byte
```